# What is the top component of the 益 kanji?

Tags: kanji, radicals

Please explain the origin/sense/meaning of the top component of the 益 kanji.
It doesn't seem to be any normal radical, nor any common "variation" thereof.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now, but for reference https://okjiten.jp/sp/kanji844.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Kanji was created by a character creation method called 会意(Kaii).
会意 is a method of constructing Kanji that combines two or more Kanji to form a single Kanji and synthesizes its meaning.

For example, the Kanji "休" is composed of "人" and "木" and is said to have been created to express the meaning of rest, as a person rests leaning against a tree.

So, 益 is made up of a 皿 and 水 (think of the upper part as a collapsed version of 水).
The overflowing of water(水) from the plate(皿) expresses the meaning of overflowing - Since Kanji "益" has such a meaning, which is why the words like "利益(*profit*)" and "有益(*beneficial*)" were created.

Comment: 水 ? Well, it does kinda look like it... how did you learn of that decomposition? I looked up the kanji in a couple of places and it doesn't mention that the top has anything to do with 水, nor does the 水 radical have a common variation that looks like that thing on top of 益. Sources: https://www.japandict.com/kanji/%E7%9B%8A , https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%8A%20%23kanji

Comment: @JacekKołodziejek These things can be hard to find in the English literature/website. Personally, I use a kanji dictionary, but I looked it up and found a [website](https://www.kanjipedia.jp/kanji/0000414700) that introduces it (in Japanese). By the way, [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BC%9A%E6%84%8F) is the explanation of the 会意 (also in Japanese).

Comment: That's a nice catch 22 there :p thanks.

Comment: Wiktionary often has good explanations even on the English version.

Comment: @JacekKołodziejek Bernhard Karlgren _Analytic Dictionary of Chinese and Sino-Japanese_ gives that decomposition also. (Item 197, page 83.)  Karlgreen agrees with dROOOze that in 益 the upper component has been written _sideways_.

Answer (score 10):

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state)) [璽印](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(East_Asia)) | [image: 益] | 133 珍秦齋古印 |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 益] | 秦律雜抄15 [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts) |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image: 益] | [皿部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=36) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
| [西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 益] | 相馬經5上 [馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts) |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) 隸 | [image: 益] | [華山廟碑](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8F%AF%E5%B1%B1%E5%BB%9F%E7%A2%91) |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 益] |  |

「益」 depicts a *shallow container / dish / vessel* 「皿」 (see e.g. the bottom part of [「盟」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=3135), [「盛」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2278), etc.) with *water* [「水」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=147) overflowing from the top, indicating the original meaning *to overflow*; this word is now complexified into 「{{zh-tw:溢}}」, made by adding an additional 「水・氵」.

The original character 「益」 was later extended to mean *to gain, benefit*, which is its modern definition.

Note that in 「益」, 「水」 is written **sideways**. For reference, you can compare it with something like 「清」:

<kbd>[image: 益]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 清]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- [漢語多功能字庫](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf)・[「益」](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%9B%8A)
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)

Comment: 新字源 lists some other forms: https://imgur.com/a/WhdI4nC (first two). Are these consistent with what you listed or contradictory? If contradictory which source should be considered more authoritative?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Great question. I didn't mention those in the answer to avoid over-complicating things, but here's the jist. Indeed, a [more complete survey](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1777) of this character will have included those forms, but they technically aren't immediately relevant to the glyph 「益」: (1) while it is widely considered to be completely interpretable as 「益」, the [bronze inscription forms](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen?kaiOrder=1777) (second one in your image) is actually 八 + 血 rather than 水 + 皿.

Comment: (2) The [oracle bone forms](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jiaguwen?kaiOrder=1777) (first one in your image) is in debate to whether they can be read as 「益」 or not; besides, even if they could be, there's a 600 year gap between the end of Shang oracle bones and the Warring States Qin era, and there isn't a clear 水 in those shapes. (3) The 「益」 that we use today is only clearly descended from the Warring States Qin form, which is why the table in the answer starts from that period.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Among what I learned in the past few years on Twitter is that you can't put too much trust on the character etymology pictures in Japanese kanji dictionaries. They tend to be wrong or outdated.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!